# A word or idiom similar to sour grapes but simply not hating the object you cannot obtain?

Tags: idioms, synonyms, popular-refrains

I am looking for a word or idiom which can express a feeling similar to the sour grapes idiom but instead of putting down or hating the thing you cannot obtain, you just simply do not want it anymore.

You know, when you don't get anything you want at all that simply any desire to want something or future things simply disappears. Something similar to not caring but deep down it still affects you a little and you know you won't get it/ achieve it.

Comment: [What do you call the someone, who cares about something but wouldn't care if it's lost?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/332773/what-do-you-call-the-someone-who-cares-about-something-but-wouldnt-care-if-it) : *apathetic*

Answer (score 1):

[Not quite right, but I suggest **ennui**](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/ennui).

> School and work fill lots of people with ennui. A terrible TV show could create ennui. **If you feel like your life is going nowhere, ennui could set in.** When you're feeling ennui, you might as well take a nap, because you're too drowsy and uninterested to do much of anything else.

Answer (score 0):

***Life is unfair***

President Kennedy, in a press conference on March 21, 1962, as quoted in [This Day in Quotes](http://www.thisdayinquotes.com/2010/03/life-is-unfair-as-john-f-kennedy.html)

> There is always inequity in life,” he said. “Some men are killed in a
>   war and some men are wounded, and some men never leave the country,
>   and some men are stationed in the Antarctic and some are stationed in
>   San Francisco. It’s very hard in military or in personal life to
>   assure complete equality. **Life is unfair**.  (Emphasis added)

You can say "Life is unfair" and mean, for example, that you accept that didn't get into your first choice of college even though you were qualified, or you can say "Life is unfair" to complain about how badly you were treated.  The OP seems to want the first meaning.